# Need help understanding removeTagsFromArray (David Powers)

Tags: php, oop

I'm working my way though David Powers OO Solutions and need help understanding one of the methods in his Pos_Validator Class.

The method name implies that it handles arrays however, the first argument calls for a ***single*** field name? The remaining args are optional. What am I missing here?

```
/**
 * Sanitizes array by removing completely all tags (including PHP and HTML).
 * 
 * The second and third optional arguments determine whether the ampersand
 * and quotes are converted to numerical entitites. By default, ampersands are
 * not converted, but both double and single quotes are replaced by numerical
 * entities.
 * 
 * Arguments four to seven determine whether characters with an ASCII value less than 32 or
 * greater than 127 are encoded or stripped. By default, they are left untouched.  
 * 
 * @param string  $fieldName       Name of submitted value to be checked.
 * @param boolean $encodeAmp       Optional; converts & to &#38; if set to true; defaults to false.
 * @param boolean $preserveQuotes  Optional; preserves double and single quotes if true; defaults to false.
 * @param boolean $encodeLow       Optional; converts ASCII values below 32 to entities; defaults to false.
 * @param boolean $encodeHigh      Optional; converts ASCII values above 127 to entities; defaults to false.
 * @param boolean $stripLow        Optional; strips ASCII values below 32; defaults to false.
 * @param boolean $stripHigh       Optional; strips ASCII values above 127; defaults to false.
 */
public function removeTagsFromArray($fieldName, $encodeAmp = false, $preserveQuotes = false, $encodeLow = false, $encodeHigh = false, $stripLow = false, $stripHigh = false)
{
    // Check that another validation test has not been applied to the same input
    $this->checkDuplicateFilter($fieldName);
    // Set the filter options 
    $this->_filterArgs[$fieldName]['filter'] = FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING;
    // Multiple flags are set using the "binary or" operator
    $this->_filterArgs[$fieldName]['flags'] = FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY;
    if ($encodeAmp) {
        $this->_filterArgs[$fieldName]['flags'] |= FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_AMP;
    }
    if ($preserveQuotes) {
        $this->_filterArgs[$fieldName]['flags'] |= FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES;
    }
    if ($encodeLow) {
        $this->_filterArgs[$fieldName]['flags'] |= FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_LOW;
    }
    if ($encodeHigh) {
        $this->_filterArgs[$fieldName]['flags'] |= FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_HIGH;
    }
    if ($stripLow) {
        $this->_filterArgs[$fieldName]['flags'] |= FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW;
    }
    if ($stripHigh) {
        $this->_filterArgs[$fieldName]['flags'] |= FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH;
    }
}
```

Comment: Without more context (not familiar with the resource) I can't say why the method is named `removeTagsFromArray()`. But according to its definition and doc block, it definitely operates on a string, setting validation properties for the string field name in `$this->_filterArgs()`.

Answer (score 1):

It's a long time since I wrote that book, so I can't remember everything I had in mind at the time. But that particular method of the Pos_Validator class works as expected.

The first argument is the name of the input field. Unlike IDs, which must be unique, the name attribute can be used for multiple input fields. To submit multiple fields as an array to a PHP script, you add a pair of square brackets at the end of the name attribute. For example, the following code submits the two address fields as an array:

```
<p><label for="address1">Address 1:</label>
    <input name="address[]" type="text" id="address1">
</p>
<p><label for="address2">Address 2:</label>
    <input name="address[]" type="text" id="address2" />
</p>
```

If you create an instance of Pos_Validator as $val, you can strip tags out of the address fields by calling the removeTagsFromArray() method like this:

```
$val->removeTagsFromArray('address');
```

Is this the most likely scenario? Possibly not. The purpose of the class was to demonstrate how to use the Facade design pattern to hide the complexity of the PHP filter functions. The other methods of the Pos_Validator class are more practical.